# Python sas7bdat module usage

Tags: python, sas

I have to dump data from SAS datasets.  I found a Python module called sas7bdat.py that says it can read SAS .sas7bdat datasets, and I think it would be simpler and more straightforward to do the project in Python rather than SAS due to the other functionality required.  However, the help(sas7bdat) in interactive Python is not very useful and the only example I was able to find to dump a dataset is as follows:

```
import sas7bdat
from sas7bdat import *
# following line is sas dataset to convert
foo = SAS7BDAT('/support/sas/locked_data.sas7bdat')
#following line is txt file to create
foo.convertFile('/support/textfiles/locked_data.txt','\t')
```

This doesn't do what I want because a) it uses the SAS variable names as column headers and I need it to use the variable labels, and b) it uses "nan" to denote missing numeric values where I'd rather just leave the value blank.

Can anyone point me to some useful documentation on the methods included in sas7bdat.py?  I've Googled every permutation of key words that I could think of, with no luck.  If not, can someone give me an example or two of using readColumnAttributes(), readColumnLabels(), and/or readColumnNames()?

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 9):

As time passes, solutions become easier. I think this one is easiest if you want to work with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sas('/support/sas/locked_data.sas7bdat')
```

Note that it is easy to get a numpy array by using `df.values`

Answer (score 4):

This is only a partial answer as I've found no [easy to read] concrete documentation.

You can view the source code [here](http://git.pyhacker.com/sas7bdat/src/064775a8d50f4d47ff295bb0506458816c494804/sas7bdat.py?at=master)

This shows some basic info regarding what arguments the methods require, such as:

- readColumnAttributes(self, colattr)
- readColumnLabels(self, collabs, coltext, colcount)
- readColumnNames(self, colname, coltext)

I think most of what you are after is stored in the "header" class returned when creating an object with SAS7BDAT.  If you just print that class you'll get a lot of info, but you can also access class attributes as well.  I think most of what you may be looking for would be under foo.header.cols.  I suspect you use various header attributes as parameters for the methods you mention.

Maybe something like this will get you closer?

```
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
foo = SAS7BDAT(inFile) #your file here...

for i in foo.header.cols:
    print '"Atrributes"', i.attr
    print '"Labels"', i.label
    print '"Name"', i.name
```

edit: Unrelated to this specific question, but the [type()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) and [dir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) commands come in handy when trying to figure out what is going on in an unfamiliar class/library

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late for the answer, but in case someone searches for similar question. The best option is:

```
import sas7bdat
from sas7bdat import *
foo = SAS7BDAT('/support/sas/locked_data.sas7bdat')
# This converts to dataframe:
ds = foo.to_data_frame()
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think the better approach would be to export the data using SAS then process the external file as needed using Python.

In SAS, you can do this...

```
libname datalib "/support/sas";
filename sasdump "/support/textfiles/locked_data.txt";

proc export
    data = datalib.locked_data
    outfile = sasdump
    dbms = tab
    label
    replace;
run;
```

The downside to this is that while the column labels are used rather than the variable names, the labels are enclosed in double quotes. When processing in Python, you may need to programmatically remove them if they cause a problem. I hope that helps even though it doesn't use Python like you wanted.

Comment: Not everyone has access to SAS -- you just have to shell out several thousand dollars per user for this solution. Ouch! If you're going to process the data in Python anyhow, using a python library to load the data also minimizes the software dependencies and makes it possible to automate processing over many SAS datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it's very difficult to find documentation. After hours of trying different things and searching, I finally looked at the source code (found here: https://bitbucket.org/jaredhobbs/sas7bdat/src/master/sas7bdat.py) From looking at that I learned it has an option fh, which is for a file handler. So if you need to read data from s3, you can use it with s3fs this way:

```
import s3fs
import sas7bdat
from sas7bdat import *

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
f = fs.open(in_file)
with SAS7BDAT(in_file, encoding = 'latin-1', fh=f) as reader:
    my_df = reader.to_data_frame()
```

The pandas read_sas function didn't work for me since my team is not using pandas 1.5 yet and there's a bug in earlier versions which causes incorrect data when there's repeating characters